# Very basic question about vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry

The vectors $a = (2,-1,-2)$ and $b = (0,-3,4)$ are given. Determine $a$:s parallel and normal vector to $b$. 
Obviously the parallel vector should be the dot product $a \cdot b$ times the unit vector $b_{e}$ which is $(2,-1,-2) \cdot (0,-3,4) (0,-3,4) \frac{1}{5} = (0,3,-4)$. The normal vector is then calculated by subtracting the parallel vector from the original vector and thus we get $(2, -4, -6)$. This is not correct according to the book however. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Hint: what happens if you double the length of $b$? What should happen?

Comment: Nothing should happen and since I'm dividing with the length of b it should show in the calculations as well?

Comment: @Lozansky - try doing it. If you double $\mathbf{b}$, the parallel vector in your approach becomes $(2, -1, -2)\cdot (0, -6, 8) (0, -6, 8)\frac{1}{10}$. Is this the same as before? Why/Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the angle between the two vectors as $\theta$ and the following rules

$$\begin{align} 
  \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} &= \|\vec{a}\| \|\vec{b}\| \cos\theta &
  \|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\| & = \|\vec{a}\| \|\vec{b}\| \sin\theta 
\end{align} $$

Now to construct the parallel vector use the direction of $\vec{b}$ and the adjacent side of the triangle with $\vec{a}$ as the hypotenuse

$$ \vec{a}_b = \left( \frac{\vec{b}}{\| \vec{b} \|} \right) \left( \| \vec{a} \| \cos\theta \right) =  \left( \frac{\vec{b}}{\| \vec{b} \|} \right) \left( \frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{\|\vec{b}\|} \right) = \left(\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}}\right) \vec{b}$$

The normal vector is then

$$ \vec{a}_n = \vec{a} - \vec{a}_b $$

Comment: Very thorough and complete.

Answer (score 2):

When you calculate the "parallel" vector, you should not use the dot product of $a\cdot b$ but instead the *normalized* dot product $$\frac{a\cdot b}{|b|}$$ times the unit vector $b$. The projection of $a$ onto $b$ should always be independent of the length of $b$.